# php mysql pdo bindparam data not insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, bindparam

When I Call this function , it shows no error, But Data not inserted.
Database Connection is checked and its OK , Connection type PDO.

```
public function insert(){
    $table  = "category";
    $data   = array(
        'cat_id'    => 5, 
        'cat_name_en'   => 'Science', 
        'cat_info'  => 'All about nature', 
        'cat_tags'  => 'Physics, chemistry' 
        );
    $keys       = implode(', ', array_keys($data));
    $values     = ":".implode(", :", array_keys($data));
    echo $sql   = "INSERT INTO $table($keys) VALUES($values)";
    $stmt       = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bindParam(':'.$key, $value);
    }
    return $stmt->execute();

}
```

Database connection is ok. Because it works on SELECT and DELETE query, But not working INSERT and UPDATE query.
I do not want alternative but i want where is my bug.
Please help me. I am trying to solve it for 2 days.

Windows 10 64bit
WampServer 3.0.8 
PHP 7.1
MySQL 5.7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221692/cannot-insert-into-mysql-database-using-pdo-no-errors

Comment: Same type error but not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()`. Change you foreach loop to

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $value);
    }
```

See the doc:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

See the difference here:[What is the difference between bindParam and bindValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue)

Comment: try to print error `print_r($stmt->errorInfo());` after execute

Comment: Thank you. Problem is solved. It will be    bindValue().